# How can I automatically run my programs in a Terminal window & debug with Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am building a program on Mac OS that uses the `curses` library. When I attempt to run it inside Xcode, I get this error message:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

And then `curses` calls `exit`.

Obviously, it works from a Terminal window.

Is it possible to launch my program in a terminal window from Xcode? I know that I can use the "Wait for XXX to launch" option, but a lot of Xcode's helpfulness in starting programs vanishes that way, so I would be looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode uses GDB, or LLDB for debugging.

You can invoke them directly from a terminal. This way, your executable will be attached to a working one.

Try:

```
gdb path/to/my/executable
```

Then, from the GDB prompt, type:

```
run
```

To start your program in debugging mode.
Take a look at the GDB manual for learning stuff like debugging commands, breakpoints, etc.

Comment: I know I can directly use gdb or lldb to debug my program in a terminal window. However, I want to launch my program from Xcode because Xcode makes it easier; if I'm to start my program externally anyways, I might as well use the "Wait for XXX to launch" option.